# line style and thickness issue in scilab

Tags: scilab

I am trying to plot five different subplots and each subplot is consist of four different lines. I am changing line style and thickness using the code `f.children.children(1).children.line_style = 2;
f.children.children(1).children.thickness = 2;`. It works only in one plot. In case of subplots it gives error that the dimension are not consistent. Instead of my code I am writing here a simple code which also gives the same error. Will be thankful if someone help me here. The code is

```
clear;clc
p = 0:100;  t1 = p.^3; t2 = 3*p.^3-5;  //functions defined
clf();   f=gcf();
subplot(221);
  plot2d(p, t1, 3);   //function t1 plotted at (221) 
f.children.children(1).children.line_style = 1;
f.children.children(1).children.thickness = 2;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
  plot2d(p, t2, 9);      //function t2 plotted with t1 at (221)
f.children.children(1).children.line_style = 2;
f.children.children(1).children.thickness = 2;
//**********************************************************************
x = 1:100; y1 = 2*x-5; y2 = 10*x+100;   //functions y1 and y2 defined
subplot(222);
  plot2d(x, y1, 6);    //function y1 plotted at (222)
f.children.children(1).children.line_style = 1;
f.children.children(1).children.thickness = 2;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
  plot2d(x, y2, 5);   //function y2 plotted with y1 at (222)
f.children.children(1).children.line_style = 2;
f.children.children(1).children.thickness = 2;
//**********************************************************************
r = 1:100; z1 = 2*r^2-5; z2 = r.^2;    //functions z1 and z2 aredefined
subplot(223)
  plot2d(r, z1, 1);    //function z1 plotted at (223) 
f.children.children(1).children.line_style = 6;
f.children.children(1).children.thickness = 2;
//---------------------------------------------
  plot2d(r, z2, 3);    //function z2 plotted with z1 at (223)
f.children.children(1).children.line_style = 2;
f.children.children(1).children.thickness = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand exactly why through using [`gcf`](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/gcf.html) your current code fails. But I would use [`gce`](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.5.2/en_US/gce.html) to get the last entity.
I would introduce a function to set the line style and thickness, removes lots of duplication.

### Example code

```
clear;clc
p = 0:100;  t1 = p.^3; t2 = 3*p.^3-5;  //functions defined
clf();   f=gcf(); 

function set_my_line_styles(style, thickness)
    e = gce();
    e.children.line_style = style;
    e.children.thickness = thickness;
endfunction

subplot(221);
  plot2d(p, t1, 3);   //function t1 plotted at (221) 
  set_my_line_styles(1,2);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
  plot2d(p, t2, 9);      //function t2 plotted with t1 at (221)
  set_my_line_styles(2,2);

//**********************************************************************
x = 1:100; y1 = 2*x-5; y2 = 10*x+100;   //functions y1 and y2 defined
subplot(222);
  plot2d(x, y1, 6);    //function y1 plotted at (222)
  set_my_line_styles(1,2);
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
  plot2d(x, y2, 5);   //function y2 plotted with y1 at (222)
  set_my_line_styles(2,2);

//**********************************************************************
r = 1:100; z1 = 2*r^2-5; z2 = r.^2;    //functions z1 and z2 aredefined
subplot(223)
  plot2d(r, z1, 1);    //function z1 plotted at (223) 
  set_my_line_styles(6,2);
//---------------------------------------------
  plot2d(r, z2, 3);    //function z2 plotted with z1 at (223)
  set_my_line_styles(2,2);
```

### Resulting plot

[image: Subplots]

Comment: thank you so much for the code and a quick response. Its work and make it much easier.

Comment: No problem! When you find yourself typing two or more lines more than once, always make a function :)